# Error in Multiple conditions check on multiple columns in pandas dataframe using a single IF statement

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
IndentNo    WBS_code    PurchaseGroup   MaterialCode    Dept
100003345   C-3022-02-01    DP1           23456        Service
100003348   Q/8879          DP6           23459        Undefined
110022345   Q/7668          DP2            29          Service - Capital
140003345   M/678           DP1           2290         Service - Maintenance
```

I want add another column `role_name` based on following logic:

```
if PurchaseGroup is in ['DP1','DP2','DP3','DP4','DP5','DP6'] but 
'WBS_code' doesn't start with 'Q' or 'M', then role_name == 'Service'
if PurchaseGroup =='DP1' or PurchaseGroup =='DP2' and 'WBS_code' starts with 'Q',
then role_name == 'Service-Capital'
if first 2 digit in 'IndenNo' is 14 and 'WBS_code' starts with 'M', 
then role_name=='Service- Maintenance'
```

With the above rule I have tried the following code:

```
pg = ['DP1','DP2','DP3','DP4','DP5','DP6']
def string_search_test(x):
  if ((x['PurchaseGroup'] in pg) and ((x['WBS_code'][0]!='M') or (x['WBS_code'][0]!='Q'))):
    dept ='Services'
  elif ((x['PurchaseGroup'] in pg[0:2]) and ((x['WBS_code'][0]=='M') and (x['IndentNo'][0:2]=='14'))):
    dept ='Service-Maintenance'
  elif ((x['PurchaseGroup'] in pg[0:2]) and (x['WBS_code'][0]=='Q')):
    dept = 'Service-Capital'
  else:
    dept = 'test'
  return dept

df['role_name'] = df.apply(string_search_test,axis=1)
```

I am getting the below dataframe:

```
IndentNo    WBS_code    PurchaseGroup   MaterialCode    Dept                role_name
100003345   C-3022-02-01    DP1           23456        Service                Service
100003348   Q/8879          DP6           23459        Undefined              Service <--Mismatch
110022345   Q/7668          DP2            29          Service - Capital      Service <--Mismatch
140003345   M/678           DP1           2290         Service - Maintenance  Service <--Mismatch
```

Clearly there are mismatches in all three rows as indicated.

What I am  missing here? Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Your condition seems wrong: `x['WBS_code'][0]!='M') or (x['WBS_code'][0]!='Q')`. If I understood correctly it should be `and` and not `or`

Answer (score 0):

#### Identifying the logical error

It appears the logic error is in the first if-statement. Breaking it down:

```
if (
        x['PurchaseGroup'] in pg
        and (x['WBS_code'][0]!='M'
             or x['WBS_code'][0]!='Q')
   ):
```

Each row has a valid PurchaseGroup, so `x['PurchaseGroup'] in pg` is always True. For the code check, the expectation is that the code must not start with "M" ***and*** not start with "Q". However it has an `or` operation, so in the case that the code starts with M:

```
(False or True)
= True
```

Both conditions are satisfied and the first if-statement is always executed.

#### Sidenote: prettifying your code

PurchaseGroup and WBS_code can be stored in variables to avoid repeat indexing. For testing prefixes in WBS_code, you can use [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) instead of indexing the string so it reads more like english. It also allows testing multiple prefixes.

Applying the changes:

```
def string_search_test(df):
    purchase_group = df['PurchaseGroup']
    WBS_code = df['WBS_code']

    if purchase_group in pg and not WBS_code.startswith(('M', 'O')):
        dept = 'Services'
    elif purchase_group == 'DP1' or purchase_group == 'DP2' and WBS_code.startswith('Q'):
        dept = 'Service-Capital'
    elif df['IndentNo'].startswith('14') and WBS_code.startswith('M'):
        dept = 'Service-Maintenance'
    else:
        dept = 'test'

    return dept
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However upon running this, it is not able to recognize 'Service-Capital'

Comment: @pythondumb fixed the condition to match your logic; my prior condition was imposing the "Q" WBS requirement onto DP1.